# What exactly are the Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges awarded for?

Tags: support, badges

In the Badge section, what is meant by the following badges:

> Tenacious: Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total
>   Unsung Hero:  Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

What are more than 5 and 20% of total, more than 10 and 25% of total?

Comment: Questions like this one, which are about the Stack Exchange software in general, typically already have answers on the mother meta, [meta.se]. In this case it's [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60886/can-somebody-better-explain-the-tenacious-badge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "zero score accepted" answer is one the OP has awarded the green checkmark but has a net of zero votes.

The thresholds are somewhat arbitrary, but they are designed to reward people who have a *lot* of such answers by comparison to their total pool of answers.

They mean that you have to have at least [5|10] such answers and those totals have to be at least [20|25]% of the total number of answers you have provided.

These badges are fairly rare.

Comment: Do you actually get them taken away once you do no longer fulfill the requirement?

Comment: @Sanya [No, they're not taken away](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187466/does-the-tenacious-badge-ever-get-removed). Normally no badges are taken away (except for tag badges where the tag is removed). The worst that happens is, say, you earn 10+ score on an answer, earn a Nice Answer badge, and then delete the answer; in that case you keep the badge but you won't be awarded an "extra" badge next time you make 10+ score.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty thank you :)

Comment: An alternative way to look at things: Not all of the SE badges are "good". For example, there's the Tumbleweed badge. This badge appears to have been designed to chase ill-informed noobs away. (Interestingly, both dmckee and DavidZ have won this badge.) A couple of other negative badges, at least on stackoverflow and superuser, are the Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges. That negativity may not be the case on the scientific elements of the SE network.